# Convert array from php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have array from database with json_encode, like this :

```
"[{"uid":"595e7d","name":"Elephant"},{"uid":"701b03","name":"Bird"},{"uid":"29a8c","name":"Lion"}]"
```

but how to make the array just display the record not with the field/column name, when i show in javascript like this :

javascript array :

```
{ 
    "595e7d": "Elephant",
    "701b03": "Bird",
    "29a8c": "Lion" 
}
```

whether it should be done in php or javascript?

thankyou

Comment: The desired output that you posted is not a javascript array, its an object

Comment: @HectorBarbossa , oh thankyou for the explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle with javascript:

```
function transfrom (arrs){
  return arrs.reduce((init, arr) => {
      init[arr.uid] = arr.name
      return init
  }
 , {})
}

//usage

let arrs = [{"uid":"595e7d","name":"Elephant"},{"uid":"701b03","name":"Bird"},{"uid":"29a8c","name":"Lion"}]
transfrom(arrs)

// {595e7d: "Elephant", 701b03: "Bird", 29a8c: "Lion"}
```

Or you can handle it with PHP:

```
<?php
$arr = array (
  array('uid' =>"595e7d", "name"=>"Elephant"), 
  array("uid" =>"701b03", "name" =>"Bird"), 
  array("uid" =>"29a8c", "name" =>"Lion")
); 

function transform($v1, $v2) {
    $v1[$v2["uid"]] = $v2["name"];
    return $v1;    
} 

echo json_encode(array_reduce($arr, "transform", array())); 
// { 
//     "595e7d": "Elephant",
//     "701b03": "Bird",
//     "29a8c": "Lion" 
// }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, you are looking for something like

```
 var arr = [{"uid":"595e7d","name":"Elephant"},{"uid":"701b03","name":"Bird"},{"uid":"29a8c","name":"Lion"}];
 var out = {};
 arr.forEach(function(obj){
    var tempArr = Object.values(obj);
    out[tempArr[0]] = tempArr[1]; 
 });

 console.log(out);
```

Please note that the code is not too generic and may require modification based on your actual requirement.